# Python numpy index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

i have a numpy array p like this:

```
array([[ 0.92691702,  0.07308298],
   [ 0.65515095,  0.34484905],
   [ 0.32526151,  0.67473849],
   ..., 
   [ 0.34171992,  0.65828008],
   [ 0.77521514,  0.22478486],
   [ 0.96430103,  0.03569897]])
```

If i do x=p[:,1:2], i would get

`array([[ 0.07308298],
       [ 0.34484905],
       [ 0.67473849],
       ..., 
       [ 0.65828008],
       [ 0.22478486],
       [ 0.03569897]])`
and x.shape is (5500,1)

However, if i do x=p[:,1], i would get

```
array([ 0.07308298,  0.34484905,  0.67473849, ...,  0.65828008,
    0.22478486,  0.03569897])
```

and x.shape is (5500, )

Why there is difference like this? It quite confuses me.  Thanks all in advance for your help.

Comment: Same thing with lists: `[1,2,3][1]` is not the same as `[1,2,3][1:2]`. Try understanding this example first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the difference between using a slice and a single integer in the `ndarray.__getitem__` call.  Slicing causes the ndarray to return *"views"* while integers cause the ndarray *values*.

I'm being a little loose in my terminology here -- Really, for your case they both return a numpy view -- It's easier to consider just the 1D case first:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(10)
>>> x[1]
1
>>> x[1:2]
array([1])
```

This idea extends to multiple dimensions nicely -- If you pass a slice for a particular axis, you'll get "array-like" values along that axis.  If you pass a scalar for a particular axis, you'll get scalars along that axis in the result.

Note that the 1D case really isn't any different from how a standard python `list` behaves:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> x[1]
2
>>> x[1:2]
[2]
```

Comment: It's not the view/value distinction that's important here; it's the item/subsequence distinction. In fact, both operations return views for this case.

Comment: @user2357112 -- Of course you're right.  I was trying to draw an analogy with the 1D case, but I suppose I wasn't explicit enough.  Updated.

Comment: Thank you all, your answers really help, i understand that now. If i use slicing, i will get a sub sequence, if i use integer, i will only get the item.